# How to add two different date picker on one page and style them separately?

Tags: html, jquery, css, datepicker

I need build two same date picker in one page. For that I use jQuery datepicker, the problem is, I need make for both of them little bit different styles, but I cannot. I connect 2 datepicker with different id, but script build same picker on the end of DOM.
Pls, tell me if possible control html structure which build by datepicker and how to give them different style in one page?

```
$( function() {
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
});
$("#datepicker").datepicker( "setDate", 7);
} );
$( function() {
$("#datepickerModal").datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
});
$("#datepickerModal").datepicker( "setDate", 7);
} );
```

Comment: You just changed their id, nothing else! How do you want to style them differently, Can  you be more specific?

Comment: I download jQuery css and style from this file, but problem is this give same styles for both of this datepicker

Comment: Obviously its going to show up exactly the same unless you have different css for each, Can you be alot more be specific about how you want to make them different from eachother?

Comment: I need to find way give them classes for styling separately

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this actually hurts performance, but I don't like to import or have a bunch of unused CSS classes on my page. As I didn't find a specific CSS file for the datepicker on the Jquery-UI website, **I didn't import (CSS file from jquery-ui)** and customize it myself, but I think overwriting the default stylesheet would also work.

[Read more about here](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#theming)

Look an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Custom Style for Jquery UI datepicker</title>
<!-- Using Google material icons font for prev, next calendar buttons -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
body {
  width: 98vw;
  height: 98vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
}

.icon {
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #5a5a5a;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
}

header {
  flex: 0 0 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
header > #datepicker_button {
  width: -webkit-max-content;
  width: -moz-max-content;
  width: max-content;
  position: relative;
}
header > #datepicker_button.opened #datepicker_area {
  display: block;
}
header > #datepicker_button > span {
  margin: 0;
}
header > #datepicker_button > #datepicker_area {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
}

section {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
section > p {
  margin: 0;
}
section > code {
  margin: 0;
}

footer {
  flex: 0 0 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
footer > #datepicker-2_button {
  width: -webkit-max-content;
  width: -moz-max-content;
  width: max-content;
  position: relative;
}
footer > #datepicker-2_button.opened #datepicker-2_area {
  display: block;
}
footer > #datepicker-2_button > span {
  margin: 0;
}
footer > #datepicker-2_button > #datepicker-2_area {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 0;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------ */
/* Jquery UI Date Picker */
#ui-datepicker-div {
  display: none !important;
}

#_datepicker > .ui-datepicker {
  font-family: system-ui;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.9294117647);
  border: 0 !important;
  padding: 6px;
}
#_datepicker > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: -webkit-max-content auto -webkit-max-content;
  grid-template-columns: max-content auto max-content;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2784313725);
}
#_datepicker > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-header > .ui-datepicker-prev {
  grid-column: 1/2;
}
#_datepicker > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-header > .ui-datepicker-next {
  grid-column: 3/4;
}
#_datepicker > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-header .ui-icon {
  font-family: "Material Symbols Outlined";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  font-feature-settings: "liga";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  padding: 4px;
}
#_datepicker > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-header > .ui-datepicker-title {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  color: #dbdbdb;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #444444;
}
#_datepicker > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-header > .ui-datepicker-title > span {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
}
#_datepicker > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-calendar {
  margin-top: 6px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
#_datepicker > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-calendar > thead {
  margin: 0;
}
#_datepicker > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-calendar > thead > tr {
  margin: 0;
}
#_datepicker > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-calendar > thead > tr > th {
  margin: 0;
}
#_datepicker > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-calendar > thead > tr > th > span {
  color: #dfdfdf;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
}
#_datepicker > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-calendar > tbody {
  margin: 0;
}
#_datepicker > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-calendar > tbody > tr {
  margin: 0;
}
#_datepicker > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-calendar > tbody > tr > td {
  width: 37px;
  min-width: 37px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0509803922);
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: end;
}
#_datepicker > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-calendar > tbody > tr > td > a {
  color: #e7e7e7;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-variant-caps: all-small-caps;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px black;
}

#_datepicker_2 > .ui-datepicker {
  font-family: system-ui;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.93);
  border: 0 !important;
  padding: 6px;
}
#_datepicker_2 > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: -webkit-max-content auto -webkit-max-content;
  grid-template-columns: max-content auto max-content;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2784313725);
}
#_datepicker_2 > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-header > .ui-datepicker-prev {
  grid-column: 1/2;
}
#_datepicker_2 > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-header > .ui-datepicker-next {
  grid-column: 3/4;
}
#_datepicker_2 > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-header .ui-icon {
  font-family: "Material Symbols Outlined";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  font-feature-settings: "liga";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  padding: 4px;
}
#_datepicker_2 > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-header > .ui-datepicker-title {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  color: #3c3c3c;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #cfcfcf;
}
#_datepicker_2 > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-header > .ui-datepicker-title > span {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
}
#_datepicker_2 > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-calendar {
  margin-top: 6px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
#_datepicker_2 > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-calendar > thead {
  margin: 0;
}
#_datepicker_2 > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-calendar > thead > tr {
  margin: 0;
}
#_datepicker_2 > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-calendar > thead > tr > th {
  margin: 0;
}
#_datepicker_2 > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-calendar > thead > tr > th > span {
  color: #707070;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3411764706);
}
#_datepicker_2 > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-calendar > tbody {
  margin: 0;
}
#_datepicker_2 > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-calendar > tbody > tr {
  margin: 0;
}
#_datepicker_2 > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-calendar > tbody > tr > td {
  width: 37px;
  min-width: 37px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.19);
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: end;
}
#_datepicker_2 > .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-calendar > tbody > tr > td > a {
  color: #545454;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-variant-caps: all-small-caps;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div id="datepicker_button">
    <span class="icon material-symbols-outlined">&#xebcc;</span>
    <div id="datepicker_area"><div id="_datepicker"></div></div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section>
    <p>
    THE "SECRET" TO SHOW THE GOOGLE ICONS ON THE BUTTONS IS TO CHANGE THE INNER TEXT OF PREV , NEXT BUTTONS AND SET THE "UI-ICON" STYLE OF THE DATEPICKER HEADER SAME AT GOOGLE MATERIAL .
    </p>
    <code>
      .ui-datepicker > .ui-datepicker-header .ui-icon {
        font-family: "Material Symbols Outlined";
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 1;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        text-transform: none;
        display: inline-block;
        white-space: nowrap;
        word-wrap: normal;
        direction: ltr;
        -webkit-font-feature-settings: "liga";
        font-feature-settings: "liga";
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        padding: 4px;
        }
    </code>
  </section>
  <footer><div id="datepicker-2_button">
  <span class="icon material-symbols-outlined">&#xebcc;</span>
  <div id="datepicker-2_area"><div id="_datepicker_2"></div></div>
  </div></footer>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $("#datepicker_button").on('click', function(e) {
      $("#datepicker_button").toggleClass("opened");
    });
    $("#datepicker-2_button").on('click', function(e) {
      $("#datepicker-2_button").toggleClass("opened");
    });

    $("#_datepicker").datepicker({
        // You can change next , prev inner text to work with google icons font
        // https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-nextText
        nextText: "arrow_forward_ios",
        prevText: "arrow_back_ios"
    });

    $("#_datepicker_2").datepicker({
        // You can change next , prev inner text to work with google icons font
        // https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-nextText
        nextText: "arrow_forward_ios",
        prevText: "arrow_back_ios"
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/EdvaldoFilho/f5mbpn0q/32/

Note that example has Google material icons font beside default font icons from jQuery in datepicker header... If you don't want use that, just remove font from header and clear datepicker options. Otherwise:
https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.query=ios